# SQLite db data not copied to LocalFolder in Windows 8.1 Store App

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite

I'm including a pre-existing SQLite db with tables and data to a Win 8.1 Store App.

During development with VS 2013 when the app is run the first time the db gets copied to the correct LocalFolder. However when the app is deployed via sideloading to any other machine using the Store-->Create App Packages, only a file (0 bytes) get created in the LocalFolder with no data or tables.

Below is my code:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        CopyDatabase();
       InitializePage();
        DataSetup();

    }


private async Task CopyDatabase()
    {
        bool isDatabaseExisting = false;

        try
        {
            StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ExpressEMR.db3");
            isDatabaseExisting = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("DB exists");
        }
        catch
        {
            isDatabaseExisting = false;
            Debug.WriteLine("DB not  exists");
        }

        if (!isDatabaseExisting)
        {
            StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("ExpressEMR.db3");
            await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
            Debug.WriteLine("DB copied");
        }
    }
```

My code follows most of the web examples of using a pre-existing SQLite db.  Any help or pointers is appreciated.

How do I get the db copied with it's data included on the new device?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue you are having is that you have not correctly added the database to be copied to your project. Your code should be fine if you first add the database to your project then set the properties of the database to:

1. Build Action: Content
2. Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer

Once you have done this you will need to redeploy your project and it should all sync correctly.
[image]